# MongoDB: Server sockets closed after a few minutes

Tags: mongodb, aws

I am working with multiple `AWS intances` connected to the same `MongoDB` database (inside `Compose.io` Elastic deployment). But i am getting the error `server <url>:<port> sockets closed` after a few minutes. Can anyone give me any hint about what may be wrong with the connection code?

**CONNECTION CODE**

```
var url = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<url1>:<port1>,<url2>:<port2>/<dbName>?replicaSet=<replicaSetName>"; 
var options = { 
    server : {"socketOptions.keepAlive": 1}, 
    replSet : { "replicaSet": <replicaSetName>, "socketOptions.keepAlive": 1 } 
}; 
MongoClient.connect(url, options, function(err, db) { ... });
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] MongoError: server <url>:<port> sockets closed 
at null. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:47) 
at g (events.js:199:16) 
at emit (events.js:110:17) 
at null. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:101:12) 
at g (events.js:199:16) 
at emit (events.js:110:17) 
at Socket. (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:142:12) 
at Socket.g (events.js:199:16) 
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17) 
at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

Comment: As this is more a nodejs issue probably, please have a look at StackOverflow or create a question there : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mongodb]+mongoerror+sockets+closed

Answer (score 0):

First a probably silly question, are you replacing all the , , etc placeholders with the actual values from your `compose.io` database?

If you are already doing that, maybe you can debug the connection using the `mongo shell` to connect to your DB instances.

If you have local install of `mongodb` you can use:

> mongo host:port/database-name -u user -ppassword

This is also what `compose.io` docs recommend for connection debugging https://docs.compose.io/common-questions/how-to-connect-to-mongodb.html

Answer (score 0):

It could be also that max connections is reached (if you configured that)

```
2015-12-08T08:49:10.964+0000 I NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.34.21:5345 #184 (26 connections now open)
2015-12-08T08:49:10.964+0000 I NETWORK [initandlisten] connection refused because too many open connections: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/) if you shall connect to a `ReplicaSet` consisting of `one primary` and `1` or `more secondaries`. To Do this we need to supply the `driver` with a `seedlist` of servers and the name of the `ReplicaSet` we wish to connect to. Let’s take a look at a code example.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018/myproject?replicaSet=foo';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

For further your ref [Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) & [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with MongoDB specifically, but I have noticed that AWS will sever TCP connections (each end thinks the other end closed it) after 5 minutes of idleness, and that the keepalive setting does not prevent this.

I've noticed this both with `PostgreSQL` streaming replication, 5 minutes like clockwork, as evidenced by the log entries that the connection was lost and reestablished.  Also with `ssh`, but I haven't timed it there.  Go make a cup of tea, come back and your connection is gone.